# :last-of-type selector not working inside media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/sNeR7

The border under the text "Of this I am absolutely certain; that to claim absolute certainty is a fool's enterprise." shouldn't be there, since I have added this style rule:

`.bannerItem:last-of-type
            {
                border-bottom: none!important
            }`

inside `@media(max-width: 40em)
        { ... }`.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I don't see that style rule anywhere in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) realize that it only searches for the last element of a certain **type** (`p`, `div`, etc) within a parent, not a class or ID value.  Since all of the children within `.bannerHolder` are of the same type, using `:last-of-type` properly would've ended up selecting `.bannerPager` instead, since its the last child div of its parent.

If you want to style the last `.bannerItem` within `.bannerHolder`you can use:

```
.bannerHolder div.bannerItem:nth-child(3) {border-bottom: none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sNeR7/3/

You can also use the adjacent sibling combinator to support older versions of IE:

```
.bannerHolder .bannerItem + .bannerItem + .bannerItem {border-bottom: none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sNeR7/2/

**Note** that `:nth-child()` also doesn't search for an elements class, it only cares about whether or not an element is a child of its parent. So adding the class above isn't actually necessary.

Comment: _“it only searches for the last element within a parent of a certain type”_ – that was phrased so that it could be misunderstood easily (not the parent has to be of that type, the searched element has to). Allow me to switch those two parts around, I think that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`:last-of-type` selects the last element of that specific *type*, not the last element with a certain class. So in fact your selector `.bannerItem:last-of-type` will select nothing.

`div.bannerItem:last-of-type` would select the last `div` element, not the last element with class `.bannerItem`.

Since your markup contains `div` after `.bannerItem`, your selector will not work as you expect it to.

Assuming that there could be any number of `.bannerItems` I don't think there is actually a way to do what you are trying to do with pure css selectors.

If there will always be three you could use:

```
.bannerItem:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom: none!important
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNeR7/4/)